# Can we create a vector of Eigen Matrix?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

Is it possible to create a vector of Eigen Matrix?

For example, I run the following line,

```
vector<Matrix<double,4,1>> vector_of_matrix;
```

but I receive the following error,

```
error: template argument 3 is invalid
error: template argument 4 is invalid
error: template argument 6 is invalid
error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Anyone care to enlighten me as to how we would properly initialise a vector of eigen matrices? Note, I have considered the Eigen dynamic sized matrix as an alternative, but I do not want this.

Comment: Did you  `#include <Eigen/StdVector>`?

Comment: I haven't. I am attempting to add it now. But when I do "#include <eigen3/Eigen/StdVector>" I get the following error: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/StlSupport/StdVector.h:14:42: fatal error: Eigen/src/StlSupport/details.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Eigen/src/StlSupport/details.h"

Comment: You should set include path to `.../eigen3`, so the #include's in the header files could get the internal header files.

Comment: fyi, apparently changing it to "#include "eigen3/Eigen/src/StlSupport/details.h"" within the StdVector.h file fixed it.

Comment: I would not recommend editing the Eigen library files yourself to fix this include error. Although you can see and edit the source code for this library you should treat it like any other third party library and only edit it if you really know what you are doing otherwise you are setting yourself up for surprises when random things stop working in the future. In this case you just need to add `/usr/include/eigen3` to the include path for your project to fix the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html), you must

```
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
```

and use

```
std::vector<Matrix<double,4,1>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Matrix<double,4,1> > >
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use space while you specify template structures. Else c++ wont be able to parse it.

```
vector<Matrix<double,4,1> > vector_of_matrix;
```

Comment: unless you are use c++11

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to `#include` required headers  `<Eigen/Core>` and (C++ standard) `<vector>`.

Depending on age of your compiler, it is necessary to have spaces between greater than and less than signs  (e.g. `> >` rather than `>>` to avoid compiler confusion).    Older standards require this.